# How to seperate 2 DIVS Completely apart from eachother (footer)

Tags: html, css

Okay so what I need to do that I can't seen to figure out is I have DIVs under a container but I want to put a completely different separate div so I can put info or whatever I need in that DIV, problem is that the DIV keeps sticking to the DIV's above it I tried Position: Absolute, Bottom: 0 - and I tried padding-top but it seems to just space the div inside the container. I knew how to do it I just cant seem to remember I also tried clear: both, but maybe I am putting it in the right place I forget. I also think maybe I should be using something different to put the 3 divs above together with something else other then float: left.. I am not too sure some help would be great! Thanks! It would help me get back on track

HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index2.css">
    </head>

    <body>
      <div id="container">
          <div id="div1">THIS IS DIV 1</div>
          <div id="div2">THIS IS DIV 2</div>
          <div id="div3">THIS IS DIV 3</div>
      </div>

      <div id="footer">I want this div to be separated from t
          the other ones above. Not only a space between them
          but also to be completly seperate from the others not
          with spacing.
      </div>
      </div> 
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
#container {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 500px;
    height: 300px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
#div1 {
    float: left;
    width: 33.3%;
    height: 200px;
}
#div2 {
    float: left;
    width: 33.3%;
    height: 200px;
}
#div3 {
    float: left;
    width: 33.3%;
    height: 200px;
}
#footer {
    width: 500px;
    height: 300px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
#foot1 {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Comment: Try this in css, for `#footer` remove `margin-left` and `margin-right` and add, for example `margin:10px auto 0px;`. `10px` move Your div down from above divs, `auto` will center Your div (that `auto` is for `left` and `right` margin, and last one `0px` is margin for `bottom`). `margin:10px auto 0px;` is equivalent for `margin-top:10px; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; margin-bottom:0px;` ... there is fiddle example : https://jsfiddle.net/9ztkwdc5/

Answer (score 0):

Just add `margin-top` to your footer `div`:

```
margin-top: 20px;
```

Check out this [**demo**](http://jsbin.com/magosuqujo/edit?html,output)